# Translating C++ member initialisation constructor to Julia

Tags: c++, class, struct, julia

I have this class in C++ and want to replicate it in Julia.

```cpp
class Clock
{
  double epsilon;
  double dt;
  int64_t timestep;
  double t;
  Clock(double _epsilon=1e-14) : epsilon(_epsilon)
};
```

So far I have

```
mutable struct Clock
    epsilon::Float64
    dt::Float64
    timestep::Int64
    t::Float64
    #Need the constructor#
end
```

Comment: How does C++ initialize those other fields you haven't assigned in the constructor? Randomly, or with zero defaults? Is there a concept of "uninitialized"? (Maybe add that to the question, not everybody knows C++).

Comment: This seems not to be about translating but rather just about how to write a constructor and/or to express scientific notation in Julia. That said, C++ is case-sensitive, so `Class Clock` won't work. @phipsgabler The basic fields that aren't explicitly initialised will have undefined values and can't be read until they are assigned, so that should simply be avoided by ensuring they always get initialised. The simplest way is to add `{}` after each member's name, which ensures it's default-initialised if the constructor does not initialise it more specifically.

Comment: @underscore_d It's reasonable to call it translation if you don't know the subtleties and how the non-initialized parts map from one language to the other (that `Clock` as they wrote in Julia is immutable, and if you don't put assign the fields, you can never get rid of the random nonsense that will go there...)

Comment: I didn't realised Julia had a concept of uninitialised. Weird then that it defaults to allowing the nonsense to be immutable :-)

Comment: The difference is that uninitialized only makes sense for non-bitstypes. Bitstypes ones are default-initialized with random stuff, the others behave somewhat like you described above as "undefined" (you get an error if you access the field without assigning anything first). (It's like when you say `int a` and try to do something with `a`, except that it's not defined as undefined).

Answer (score 3):

The closest to C++ behaviour I believe would be the following:

```
mutable struct Clock
    epsilon::Float64
    dt::Float64
    timestep::Int64
    t::Int64

    Clock(epsilon=1e-14) = new(epsilon) 
end
```

This leaves the rest of the fields [incomplete](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1).  Since they have so-called [*bits types*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.isbitstype), they are actually initialized, but with undefined values (as opposed to C++, where they are uninitialized, IIUC), so accessing the fields without assignment does not error (it would be for non-bitstypes, such as arrays).

The struct has to be mutable, because otherwise you couldn't change the fields after you constructed the value and were left with a bunch of garbage forever.

But let it be said that incomplete initialization is not particularly idiomatic, or at least to be avoided whenever possible.  I'd rather write the type as follows:

```
struct Clock
    epsilon::Float64
    dt::Float64
    timestep::Int64
    t::Int64
end

Clock(epsilon=1e-14) = Clock(epsilon=epsilon, 0.0, 0, 0)
```

(or with whatever defaults make sense for you), and stick to immutable functions manipulating it.  That second variant uses an [outer constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-outer-constructor-methods-1), which is basically just a method on the type (special things like `new` and incomplete initialization are available only in inner constructors).  This outer constructor call the default-provided inner constructor.

Comment: FWIW, an uninitialised primitive in C++ has an "unspecified value" which results in undefined behaviour on access (not an error), so those semantics seem pretty equivalent in practice.